# show countdown timer in side fragment on android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, countdowntimer

I have an android app and the app has a  fragment. I want to show a timer countdown  in side fragment . how can I do this. the timer countdown  format is  YYYY-MM-DD.
after the timer finish the timer  Visibility will gone. 
I use this countdown timer on my app activity and I want to use it on fragment

Thanks..

```
public void countDownStart() {
    handler = new android.os.Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd");
                // Please here set your event date//YYYY-MM-DD
                Date futureDate = dateFormat.parse("2018-11-4");
                Date currentDate = new Date();
                if (!currentDate.after(futureDate)) {
                    long diff = futureDate.getTime()
                            - currentDate.getTime();
                    long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                    diff -= days * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                    long hours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
                    diff -= hours * (60 * 60 * 1000);
                    long minutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
                    diff -= minutes * (60 * 1000);
                    long seconds = diff / 1000;
                    txtDay.setText("" + String.format("%02d", days));
                    txtHour.setText("" + String.format("%02d", hours));
                    txtMinute.setText(""
                            + String.format("%02d", minutes));
                    txtSecond.setText(""
                            + String.format("%02d", seconds));
                } else {
                    textViewGone();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1 * 1000);
}

public void textViewGone() {


}`
```

Comment: @SonhnLab, his timer is fine. It's more a question about creating fragments.

Comment: Please say how can I do this

Comment: show your fragment and fragment' xml that you want show on

Answer (score 0):

Android has CountdownTimer, it makes you easier to do a countdown timer. You can follow this tutorial to do that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ChnwWSAN5E

Comment: You can create a new project with example fragment inside and then place that CountdownTimer inside the Fragment example, that is.